# Reading file into struct

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct

I'm trying to write a code that will read a text file and store it into a struct so I can use the struct for the program.

```c
struct Synonym{
    char Ausdruck[100];
    char Anmerkung[60];
};
typedef struct Synonym Synonym;
```

This is my struct and I'm trying to fit a file that looks like this

```
# License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301 USA
Kernfission;Fission;Kernspaltung;Atomspaltung;
Wiederaufnahme;Fortfuehrung;
wegfahren;wegfliegen;abfliegen;aufbrechen;abfahren;abduesen (ugs.);davonfahren;fortfahren;abreisen;
Training;Kurs;Workshop;Weiterbildung;Seminar;Kursus;Bildungsmassnahme;Lehrgang;
Zerlegung;Demontage;Entlassung;Abbau;
```

The lines after `#` should be removed. Each word in `Ausdruck` and there is a word in () after should be saved in `Anmerkung`.
The problem is I need like each line to be also struct cause after that in the whole program I need to be able to chose one line and two words from it for a hangman game.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Eintrag{
    char Ausdruck[100][20];
    char Anmerkung[100][20];
};
typedef struct Eintrag Eintrag;

int zeilencount(){
    int count_lines = 0;
    char chr;
    FILE *datei = fopen("wort.txt","r");

    if (datei == NULL) {
        printf( "Fehlgeschlagen\n");
    }
    chr = getc(datei);
    while (chr != EOF)
    {

       //Count whenever new line is encountered
        if (chr == '\n')
        {
           count_lines = count_lines + 1;
        }
         if (chr == '#'){
            count_lines = count_lines - 1;
        }


        //take next character from file.
        chr = getc(datei);
    }
    fclose(datei);

    count_lines ++;

    return count_lines;

}

int main(){
    int i,w,z,k;// loopindex
    //fopen
    int anzahlzeile = zeilencount();
    Eintrag eintrag[anzahlzeile];
    FILE *datei = fopen("wort.txt","r");

    if (datei == NULL) {
        printf( "Fehlgeschlagen\n");
    }
    for(i=0; i<anzahlzeile; i++){
        for(w=0; w<10; w++){
            for(z=0; z<20;z++){
                fscanf(datei,"%c", &eintrag[i].Ausdruck[w][z]);
                if(eintrag[i].Ausdruck[w][z]=='#'){
                fscanf(datei, "%*[^\n]");
                i=0;
                break;
                }
                if(eintrag[i].Ausdruck[w][z]==';')
                break;

                if(eintrag[i].Ausdruck[w][z]== '('){
                    for(k=0;k<20;k++) {
                        fscanf(datei,"%c", &eintrag[i].Anmerkung[w][k]);
                        if (eintrag[i].Anmerkung[w][k] == ')') {
                            break;
                        }
                        }

                if (eintrag[i].Ausdruck[w][z] == '\n')break;


                }

            }
        }
    }   
    for(i=0; i<anzahlzeile; i++){
        printf("zeile %i", i+1);
        for(w=0; w<10; w++){

    printf("ausdruck = %c\n",eintrag[i].Ausdruck[w]);
    printf("anmerkung = %c\n",eintrag[i].Anmerkung[w]);

        }
    }
    //fclose
    fclose(datei);
}
```

That's what I wrote so far. I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: What have you tried? All you need to do is create an array of structs, and then open a file for reading, and read (probably using `fgets`) each line, tossing out lines that begin with `#`, parsing the lines (either with pointers of `sscanf`), and copying the pieces, as needed, to individual elements of your array. Post a bit of code and we can help further.

Comment: just updated the code ! I just can't find a way to use a struct and reading from a file

Comment: Shada - I noticed when you are editing your question, you are changing your original post. That is a "No, No" on Stack Overflow. Just add your new edits/code below the original. That way people who read the answers will know what the person was answering and the answers will all make sense. If you change your question and remove earlier parts, then the answers related to the earlier parts will no longer make sense. Don't worry about fixing it this time, just make a note for future edits. (you are making good progress)

Comment: Your `struct Synonym` is radically different from `struct Eintrag` in the code; one occupies 160 bytes, the other about 4000 bytes, for example.  It seems reasonably clear that words are separated by semicolons.  However, it isn't clear to me what you're trying to get to.  Is a single line a list of synonyms?  All the words need to be listed, and treated as meaning (approximately) the same?  Should one word be in the `Ausdruck` element and the rest in the `Anmerkung`, or all in `Ausdruck` or all in `Anmerkung` — or what.  How do you know where to place the words?

Answer (score 1):

It is a little difficult to tell exactly what you are attempting to do, but if I understand correctly, you want to read the datafile you have posted, ignore lines beginning with `'#'`, read the remaining lines into `synonym[X].ausdruck`, and if the line contains `(stuff)`, read `'stuff'` into `synonym[X].anmerkung`. If that is not what you are attempting, please clarify and I'm happy to help further. (**note:** in C the variables are traditionally lowercase, I've used lowercase below)

To implement what is described above, you only need a single array of structs. Your `Zeile` does not seem to serve any purpose other than declaring 15 `synonym` (if that's not the case please explain further). To read and parse each line, you need only 2 character arrays of sufficient size for each member of `synonym`. Below, we have created a static array of `synonym` of size `MAXS` (256). (you can allocate dynamically and `realloc` as needed to handle an unknown number of line, but for example purposes we will use a simple static declaration)

`fgets` is used to read each line. A simple helper function `str_rmcrlf` trims the `newline` from the end of each string read and returns its length. Each line not beginning with `'#'` is copied to `synonym[idx].ausdruck`. `strchr` is used to check each line for `'('`. If found, the contents of `(...)` are parsed into `sbuf`. If that conversion is successful, `sbuf` is copied to `synonym[idx].anmerkung`.

Give it a try and let me know if your requirements are different than described.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXS 256
#define MAXC 128
#define MAXW 64

typedef struct {
    char ausdruck[MAXC];
    char anmerkung[MAXW];
} synonym;

ssize_t str_rmcrlf (char *str);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = {0};
    synonym synonym[MAXS] = {{{0},{0}}};
    size_t i, idx = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line in file until MAXS synonym elements filled */
    while (idx < MAXS && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp))
    {
        if (*buf == '#') continue;          /* skip beginning with '#'  */

        char sbuf[MAXW] = {0};
        char *p = NULL;
        ssize_t len = 0;

        if ((len = str_rmcrlf (buf)) == -1) /* strip crlf, get length   */
            continue;                       /* continue on error        */

        /* (you should check for short-read here) */

        strcpy (synonym[idx].ausdruck, buf);    /* copy buf to ausdruck */

        /* parse buf in anmerkung */
        if ((p = strchr (buf, '('))) {          /* check buf for '('    */
            if (sscanf (p, "(%[^)\n]", sbuf))           /* read "(...)" */
                strcpy (synonym[idx].anmerkung, sbuf);  /* copy "..."   */
        }

        idx++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
        printf ("\n  synonym[%3zu].ausdruck  : %s\n", i, synonym[i].ausdruck);
        if (*(synonym[i].anmerkung))
            printf ("  synonym[%3zu].anmerkung : (%s)\n", i, 
                    synonym[i].anmerkung);
        else
            printf ("  synonym[%3zu].anmerkung :\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}

/** stip trailing newlines and carraige returns by overwriting with
 *  null-terminating char. str is modified in place. The new length
 *  is retured on success, -1 otherwise.
 */
ssize_t str_rmcrlf (char *str)
{
    if (!str) return -1;
    if (!*str) return 0;

    char *p = str;
    for (; *p; p++) {}
    p--;

    for (; p >= str && (*p == '\n' || *p == '\r'); p--) *p = 0;

    p++;

    return (ssize_t)(p - str);
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_struct dat/synonym.txt

$ ./bin/fgets_struct dat/synonym.txt

  synonym[  0].ausdruck  : Kernfission;Fission;Kernspaltung;Atomspaltung;
  synonym[  0].anmerkung :

  synonym[  1].ausdruck  : Wiederaufnahme;Fortfuehrung;
  synonym[  1].anmerkung :

  synonym[  2].ausdruck  : wegfahren;wegfliegen;abfliegen;aufbrechen;abfahren;abduesen (ugs.);davonfahren;fortfahren;abreisen;
  synonym[  2].anmerkung : (ugs.)

  synonym[  3].ausdruck  : Training;Kurs;Workshop;Weiterbildung;Seminar;Kursus;Bildungsmassnahme;Lehrgang;
  synonym[  3].anmerkung :

  synonym[  4].ausdruck  : Zerlegung;Demontage;Entlassung;Abbau;
  synonym[  4].anmerkung :
```

**Note:** you must provide adequate space to hold the entire line. You data above will exceed the `100` chars allowed resulting in a partial or *short-read*. You can check for and handle that where indicated (or simply provide adequate storage for each line as I have done by increasing the length to `128`).

---

**Splitting Each Line Into Words**

OK, the comment now helps shed light on what you are trying to accomplish. Before we look at the implementation, let's look at C a bit. C, more so than just about any other language (except assembly), is an *exact* language. There is no syntax in C that is *close enough*.

While there may be many ways to reach a solution, as far as each line of code, and each character in each line goes -- it is either *right* -- or it is *wrong*. You have to understand why each character is needed and what it does. As for each function, either functions from the standard library, or the ones you write, you must know what parameters the function takes, what the function does with each parameter, and what each function returns.

C provides you with address-by-address access to the memory that makes up your program, and it is up to you to use and manage that memory exactly how you need it. There is no close-enough or winging-it with C. That is where its power and learning-curve comes from. You have to approach learning C with that level of detail and exactness. It takes work, just like learning any new language, but once you master the basics, the sky is the limit.

When learning C, when you run into something you don't understand - look it up. Use the primary authority of the manual pages for the standard library you are using. Use a reputable tutorial. Ask questions here. But be wary, there is a lot of code posted on so-called programming sites that is just flat wrong.

All compilers provide you with tools to help you get it right. The absolute most basic and most important are the *warnings* the compiler issues when you compile your code. Take advantage of this. Always, always, compile with *warning enabled* (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`) and do not accept your code until it compiles without warning (there are some exceptions, but they are very, very rare, and not something you will be faced with anytime in the near future)

That being said, a proper compile string for this code would look something like:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -o bin/fgets_struct_words fgets_struct_words.c
```

(replace the optimization `-O3` with `-g` on gcc to enable debugging symbols)

The code below uses the same array of structs, but within each struct is a 2D array of chars to be used as an array of strings. Very importantly, the array of struct, and each of the member is initialized to `zero/nul`. This insures that all strings will be *nul-terminated*. The number of strings in each struct has been added as `synonym[X].n`. This gives you a handy, per-struct, count of the number of words in each line. `strtok` is used to break each line into tokens (words) at each `;` or `(`.

The code simply reads each line, skips those beginning with `'#'`, tokenizes the line, then stores each word in `synonym[X].ausdruck[n]`. If the word begins with `'('`, then it is placed in `synonym[X].anmerkung[n]`. Work through both examples with the level of detail explained and let me know if you have questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXS 256
#define MAXC 128
#define MAXW 64
#define MAXL 32

typedef struct {
    char ausdruck[MAXW][MAXL];
    char anmerkung[MAXW];
    size_t n;
} synonym;

ssize_t str_rmcrlf (char *str);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = {0};
    synonym synonym[MAXS] = {{{{0}},{0},0}};
    size_t i, j, idx = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line in file until MAXS synonym elements filled */
    while (idx < MAXS && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp))
    {
        if (*buf == '#') continue;          /* skip beginning with '#'  */

        char sbuf[MAXW] = {0};
        char *p = NULL;
        ssize_t n = 0, len = 0;

        if ((len = str_rmcrlf (buf)) == -1) /* strip crlf, get length   */
            continue;                       /* continue on error        */

        /* copy each word in buf to ausdruck[n] or anmerkung[n] */
        for (p = strtok (buf, " ;"); p; p = strtok (NULL, " ;\n")) {
            if (*p == '(') {    /* copy word in () to anmerkung */
                if (sscanf (p, "(%[^)\n]", sbuf))           /* read "(...)" */
                    strcpy (synonym[idx].anmerkung, sbuf);  /* copy "..."   */
            }
            else /* copy word to array */
                strcpy (synonym[idx].ausdruck[n++], p);

        }
        synonym[idx++].n = n; /* set n, increment idx */
    }

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++) 
    {
        putchar ('\n');

        for (j = 0; j < synonym[i].n; j++)
            printf ("  synonym[%3zu].ausdruck[%2zu]  : %s\n",
                    i, j, synonym[i].ausdruck[j]);

        if (*(synonym[i].anmerkung))
            printf ("\n  synonym[%3zu].anmerkung : (%s)\n", i, 
                    synonym[i].anmerkung);
        else
            printf ("\n  synonym[%3zu].anmerkung :\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}

/** stip trailing newlines and carraige returns by overwriting with
 *  null-terminating char. str is modified in place. The new length
 *  is retured on success, -1 otherwise.
 */
ssize_t str_rmcrlf (char *str)
{
    if (!str) return -1;
    if (!*str) return 0;

    char *p = str;
    for (; *p; p++) {}
    p--;

    for (; p >= str && (*p == '\n' || *p == '\r'); p--) *p = 0;

    p++;

    return (ssize_t)(p - str);
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_struct_words dat/synonym.txt

  synonym[  0].ausdruck[ 0]  : Kernfission
  synonym[  0].ausdruck[ 1]  : Fission
  synonym[  0].ausdruck[ 2]  : Kernspaltung
  synonym[  0].ausdruck[ 3]  : Atomspaltung

  synonym[  0].anmerkung :

  synonym[  1].ausdruck[ 0]  : Wiederaufnahme
  synonym[  1].ausdruck[ 1]  : Fortfuehrung

  synonym[  1].anmerkung :

  synonym[  2].ausdruck[ 0]  : wegfahren
  synonym[  2].ausdruck[ 1]  : wegfliegen
  synonym[  2].ausdruck[ 2]  : abfliegen
  synonym[  2].ausdruck[ 3]  : aufbrechen
  synonym[  2].ausdruck[ 4]  : abfahren
  synonym[  2].ausdruck[ 5]  : abduesen
  synonym[  2].ausdruck[ 6]  : davonfahren
  synonym[  2].ausdruck[ 7]  : fortfahren
  synonym[  2].ausdruck[ 8]  : abreisen

  synonym[  2].anmerkung : (ugs.)

  synonym[  3].ausdruck[ 0]  : Training
  synonym[  3].ausdruck[ 1]  : Kurs
  synonym[  3].ausdruck[ 2]  : Workshop
  synonym[  3].ausdruck[ 3]  : Weiterbildung
  synonym[  3].ausdruck[ 4]  : Seminar
  synonym[  3].ausdruck[ 5]  : Kursus
  synonym[  3].ausdruck[ 6]  : Bildungsmassnahme
  synonym[  3].ausdruck[ 7]  : Lehrgang

  synonym[  3].anmerkung :

  synonym[  4].ausdruck[ 0]  : Zerlegung
  synonym[  4].ausdruck[ 1]  : Demontage
  synonym[  4].ausdruck[ 2]  : Entlassung
  synonym[  4].ausdruck[ 3]  : Abbau

  synonym[  4].anmerkung :
```

---

**Capturing Index for anmerkung**

In order to capture the word to which `anmerkung` is attached, you simply need to know which index in `ausdruck` it belongs to. There is no need for an entire separate 2D array. For example, you could capture the index by adding `aindex` to the `synonym` struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char ausdruck[MAXW][MAXL];
    char anmerkung[MAXW];
    size_t aindex;
    size_t n;
} synonym;
```

Then the only changes to the code needed to capture it are one new line (and wrapping the `if` in `{}`:

```
                synonym[idx].aindex = n > 0 ? n - 1 : n;/* set aindex   */
```

which shown in context fits here:

```
        if (*p == '(') {    /* copy word in () to anmerkung */
            if (sscanf (p, "(%[^)\n]", sbuf)) {         /* read "(...)" */
                strcpy (synonym[idx].anmerkung, sbuf);  /* copy "..."   */
                synonym[idx].aindex = n > 0 ? n - 1 : n;/* set aindex   */
            }
        }
```

Now whenever you fill `anmerkung`, you also save the index for the word before it. You can change your output to verify the index with:

```
    if (*(synonym[i].anmerkung))
        printf ("\n  synonym[%3zu].anmerkung : (%s) index: %zu\n", i, 
                synonym[i].anmerkung, synonym[i].aindex);
```

**Output**

```
<snip>
  synonym[  2].ausdruck[ 0]  : wegfahren
  synonym[  2].ausdruck[ 1]  : wegfliegen
  synonym[  2].ausdruck[ 2]  : abfliegen
  synonym[  2].ausdruck[ 3]  : aufbrechen
  synonym[  2].ausdruck[ 4]  : abfahren
  synonym[  2].ausdruck[ 5]  : abduesen
  synonym[  2].ausdruck[ 6]  : davonfahren
  synonym[  2].ausdruck[ 7]  : fortfahren
  synonym[  2].ausdruck[ 8]  : abreisen

  synonym[  2].anmerkung : (ugs.) index: 5
<snip>
```

One other note. You see the code:

```
synonym[idx].aindex = n > 0 ? n - 1 : n;
```

It uses a `ternary` operator to set the value of `synonym[idx].aindex` rather than setting the value blindly to `n - 1`. (much the same way we used it to open the file given on the command line or `stdin` by default)

What is a `ternary` operator? It is basically a short-hand `if,then,else` that is used inline. It reads: `(test) ? (if true code) : (if false code)` (but without the `()`). So looking again at the line. you see if `n > 0` it sets the value to `n - 1`, otherwise to `n` (which is `0`). The whole point is to protect against setting `aindex` negative if the line begins with `anmerkung` (which would represent an invalid array index).

Comment: well this looks good lots o functions in it that I haven't learn.
but what I want to do is but each word in a struct alone (the words that are separated by ; )
so I tried to build another struct that well just contains an array so I can know hwich word in the line
I don't know if u can understand me :(

Comment: Instead of each word in a `struct` alone, what about a struct that holds an array of words (1 for each word in the line). That way you have the array of structs, each representing a line, then within each struct you have the array of words associated with that line?

Comment: that sounds like what I need ! how can I do something like that

Comment: OK, I've added a second example, as well as a discussion that will hopefully help you approach C with the depth is requires. Let me know if you have any questions. (Remember - The only *dumb* question is the one you fail to ask...)

Comment: I think I understand the code now the only thing I still don't understad is f ((len = str_rmcrlf (buf)) == -1) /* strip crlf, get length   */
            continue;                       /* continue on error        */
 and function ssize_t ?
and now I'm trying to build anmerkung into anmerkung[MAXW][MAXL] so that the word in () would be connected to the word that was before it

Comment: `if ((len = str_rmcrlf (buf)) == -1)` is essentially `len = str_rmcrlf (buf)`, then `if (len == -1) ...`. All *line-oriented* input functions read the entire line (including the `'\n'` at the end). The function `str_rmcrlf` removes the `'\n'`, replacing it with a `'\0'` (and since you have to find the end of the string to do that, it returns the string length as a *fringe-benefit*). The return also provides error checking. Since a length cannot be negative, `-1` is returned if an error is encountered. So the entire line just trims the `'\n'`, returns the length and checks for errors, `:)`

Comment: `size_t` is an *unsigned* value. `ssize_t` is a *signed* value that allows returning a *negative* number. Look at the function declaration for `getline`, etc. Generally when a value (like length) can not be negative, you want an *unsigned* value, but to piggy-back error reporting using a negative while still indicating that only positive values for the parameter make sense `ssize_t` is used (a non-technical description). `ssize_t` can be thought of as `int` (or `long`) while `size_t` can be thought of as the *unsigned* values representable by an `int`.

Comment: *"anmerkung[MAXW][MAXL] so that the word in () would be connected to the word that was before it"* I would go about it another way. Add a `size_t aindex` value to the struct, then just save the index when `anmerkung` is filled. There is no need for an entire separate 2D array for that. Make sense?

Comment: Lastly, `continue;` is simply a loop control mechanism. When you `continue` in a loop, you simply jump to the next iteration of the loop, skipping all remaining code in the body of the loop. So when I use continue (such as after testing if the first char in the line is `'#'`), I am merely skipping any further processing or saving on that line and immediately skipping to read the next line.

Comment: yes that makes more sense now thanks a lot. just one more question now it's working but I actually need it for a much bigger file that has the same structure of words but I have more than 3000 lines in the file and I don't know how to change the sizes of the array. I build another function the counts the exact lines in the file but I don't know how to put in the whole program

Comment: The beauty of using the `#define MAXW` (or any of the defines) is that they can simply be changed by changing 1 value at the top of the code. If you have 3000 lines, then set `#define MAXW 3500`. (that will create 3500 rows for the array). I would also change this line `char anmerkung[MAXW];` to `char anmerkung[MAXL];` (no need for 3500 there, and 32 is more than sufficient). Then just compile and it is ready for your 3000 line file. Good luck. Ask more questions if you need to.